# ImportErrors for Scipy and Requests

Tags: python, scipy, python-requests

I have been using this python program for over a month now, and all of a sudden today I get ImportError messages for both the scipy and requests modules where they have worked before.

[image]

Prior to the commands in the above screenshot of the command prompt, I used pip to uninstall scipy and requests with `pip uninstall scipy` and `pip uninstall requests`. That was successful, and then I tried `pip3 install scipy` and `pip3 install requests`. That was successful. But when I try to run the program Bot.py, where I have to import both scipy and requests, it gives me an ImportError for requests and scipy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading the packages this way should do the job.

```
py -m pip install scipy
py -m pip install requests
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried the scipy command and got the error below. Same thing happened for the requests command.

Comment: `code` WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python38\\Scripts\\f2py.exe' -> 'C:\\Python38\\Scripts\\f2py.exe.deleteme'

Comment: I had to run those commands twice in order for it to work but it eventually did, thanks.